# ASP.NET MVC 3 update field before validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The problem I'm having right now it's that ASP.NET MVC validates the request object, *user* in this case

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
```

What I want to do is that if the user's password is left blank, do not update the password, just use the old password, but if it's set, update it.

The problem is that the framework complains that user does not has a password, even if I update the *user* object, it complains

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    user.Password = "Something";

    // more code...
}
```

Apparently it does the validation on the request object, is there a way I can skip the validation in this case, or at least delay it until I finished modifying the user object?

This is the full method code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
    {
        var oldUser = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        user.Password = oldUser.Password;
    }

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a problem of client side validation (something related to ModelState) or database (when you try to submit your changes to db) ?

Comment: When I submit the form, it calls the validation before it excecutes my controller method code, the method updates the database, it's not client side.

Comment: Not sure we understand each other well : you can't enter your controller's method, right ?

Comment: I enter, it's not Javascript, the form is submitted and a POST request is sent to the server, the framework then excecutes the validation, complains, and then excecutes the method's code, according to the debugger.

Comment: Well. Show real code, please, I suppose you have a Required attribute on property Password in your class User, am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, it's a required attribute, I'll paste the complete code on my post

Comment: Well, and you have ClientSideValidation enabled, right ? And/or a test `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: Yes, but it's not the javascript, I removed the javascript and submit the form and still get the error...

Comment: The model state is still invalid even after you set the password to something. After you do that clear the model state using `ModelState.Clear();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model state will still be invalid even after you set the password to something. After you do that try clear the model state using `ModelState.Clear();` Or modify the ModelState accordingly i.e clear the error state only for password property `ModelState.Remove("Password");`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
    {
        var oldUser = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        user.Password = oldUser.Password;
        ModelState.Clear(); // or change the state accordingly (ModelState.Remove("Password");)
    }
.......
}
```

From your posts it looks like you are ware of the `[Required]` attribute on the password field. I suggest you force javascript validation and let the user know that they cannot update the password to be blank. Or if you are updating User information in a form that doesn't include password create a new viewmodel or temp model that does not have the password field and the model is specific to that form. Post to this model and bind to this model. Then update the actual user model by using the data from the temp user model. This will be better practice to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't related to the server, it's the client side. I assume you have a `Required` attribute on the `Password` property so when MVC generates the view for the model it automatically generates client-side validation AKA [Unobtrusive validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).

You could write your own custom attribute to handle your particular scenario, however, that would mean you would also need to write your own client-side validation. The simple fix here is to remove the `Required` attribute and handle the validation on the server side.

> What I want to do is that if the user's password is left blank, do not update the password, just use the old password, but if it's set, update it.

If that is the case then your logic is actually wrong anyway. You shouldn't have the `Required` attribute on the `Password` as your rules dictate that it *can* be empty.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem, I removed the javascript validation and still get the error.

Comment: @gosukiwi So you were actually getting to the server? i.e. if you put a break point in your Action you were hitting it?